# Drawing sequences from different urns - what is the distribution?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I'd like to ask the following problem:

We have $i_1, ... , i_n$ urns with each containing pieces of papers with the numbers $1,..., n$ respectively (eg $i_1$ contains only 1-s etc).
All together we have $m$ numbers.

We draw exactly $m$ times without replacement and form sequences from drawn numbers (in the order of drawing).

What is the distribution of such sequences?

What is the distribution when we allow replacement?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean that each urn contains $m$ copies of its number?  If so, then there's no difference between replacement or non-replacement.  Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: No, i mean $i_1 + ... + i_n = m$

Comment: I see.  Well, with replacement it's just uniform.  I mean, each entry has an equal probability of being any of the options.  Without...well, it seems messy.  It's uniform until an option is depleted.  Then uniform again until the second option is depleted, and so on.  So it seems to me that you need to get a handle on when the various depletions can occur (and with what probability).  I doubt there is a simple description (though I may be missing something).

Comment: Maybe you can do something recursively.  To compute the probability that the $k^{th}$ slot is occupied by $i$ you can draw the first number and thereby reduce it to a question about the $(k-1)^{st}$ slot (with smaller parameters).  Certainly this could be automated with little difficulty.

Comment: Yeah i thought so the replacement was uniform.

Ok, good idea, ill try to see it for like 2 urn first and then get a handle on it.

I thought there was an elementary explanation which i missed

Comment: It might help if you gave a toy example, e.g. with $m=3, n=2, i_1=2, i_2=1$.  I can see four possibilities:  the pattern $1,2,1$ without replacement has probability $\frac23 \times \frac12 \times \frac11 = \frac13$ or it has probability $\frac12 \times \frac12 \times \frac11= \frac14$; with replacement it has probability $\frac23 \times \frac13 \times \frac23 =\frac{4}{27}$ or it has probability $\frac12 \times \frac12 \times \frac12 =\frac{1}{8}$.